Karate NPM - how to pass values from karate-config.js file to feature file
Please note this is a nodejs project and I use karate NPM
#! /usr/bin/env node
const karate = require("@karatelabs/karate");
karate.version = "1.3.0";
let env = process.env["KARATE_ENV"];
karate.properties["env"] = env;
console.log("karate.env: ", env);
function fn() {
  let configData = {};
  if (env == "dev") {
    configData.baseURL = "http://localhost:3010";
    configData.testData = "test/dev/";
    configData.utilityPath = "utility/";
  } else if (env == "qa") {
    configData.baseURL = "http://localhost:3010";
    configData.testData = "test/qa/";
    configData.utilityPath = "utility/";
  }
  return configData;
}
// Execute the function and store the config
var config = fn();
// Run the tests in the specified folder
karate.exec();

this is my karate-config.js file. I want to access this config data in my feature file.
I tried multiple options but it didn't worked
I tried passing it in karate.env, karate.config also tried to add it in karate.properties but all failed to get data in feature file.

Refer to the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-npm#karate-configjs
Put a karate.log() statement in your karate-config.js and make sure it is appearing on the console.
Then just refer to the standard Karate docs for everything else.

const karate = require('@karatelabs/karate');
karate.log('hai'); // Use karate.log as a function
karate.exec("-T=5");
I tried this but getting error TypeError: karate.log is not a function

@AnoopG can you please read the docs and create a separate file called karate-config.js ?  the config code should NOT go in your node entry point. I can't help any more sorry, hope someone else here has better answers. to understand the NPM option more, see if this helps: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-examples/blob/main/jbang-npm/README.md
